# How to properly study this function on its domain?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

Consider the following function:
$$f(x, y) = \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} e^{-3x^2-3xy + 2y^2}$$

I have to show that there do exist global max and min, and I have to calculate those points.

*attempts*

First of all, the domain is $D: x^2+y^2 \leq 1$, which is bounded and closed, so it's compact. Then we can invoke Weierstrass theorem that guarantees the existence of max and min.

Now I search the points in two ways: internal and boundary points.
Internal points, all ok. $\nabla f(x, y) = (0, 0)$.
A not easy couple of equations arise, but in the end $(x, y) = (0, 0)$ is a solution.

The problem arises at the boundary, because if I restrict $f$ at the boundary, which is $\partial D: x^2+y^2 = 1$, I get

$$f(x, y)\bigg|_{\partial D} = 0$$

And I cannot study that function on those points.

Yet I know that there are points on the boundary where $f$ reaches the minimum (the solution speaks about the points $a = (-1/\sqrt{10}, 3/\sqrt{10})$ and $b = (3/\sqrt{10}, 1/\sqrt{10})$

I don't understand: how we find those points on $\partial D$ if $f$ over here is zero?

Comment: There is a typo somewhere in the problem.

Comment: @TedShifrin About the function itself or about the points found?ù

Answer (score 1):

You're right - $f = 0$ everywhere on the boundary circle, so there's nothing special about $\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}(-1, 3)$ or $\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}(3,1)$ compared to other points on the circle.

But $0$ is the global minimum, which is attained everywhere on the unit circle and nowhere else. Can you see why?

Comment: Well, intuitively I would say because the square root term "is in charge": the exponential is always positive. The minimum is then reached when the square root part is minimum which happens to be when it's zero, which happens all over the boundary. But I don't know if there is a "more mathematical fine way" to say it...

Comment: Yes, that's it. The $e^{\ldots} > 0$ and the $\sqrt{\cdots} \geq 0$, so $f \geq 0$.